# How can I search users by first and last names in MongoDB/Python/Django

Tags: python, algorithm, mongodb, search

I'm using MongoDB to store a few millions of user documents.
Each document has a `first_name` and `last_name` key (column).
The visitor of the website has a *single* text box for querying the DB for users.
My goal is that inputs like:
`John Doe` and
`Doe John` and
`Dow Jones`
should return a list of possible names, such as:
`John Doe`, `Doe John`, `Dow Jones`, `Joan Doe`, `Johan Dow` etc...
Meaning, first_name/last_name-insensitive and 'sounds-like' names should be returned.

How can this be done?

Edit:
I don't HAVE to do it in the DB engine. App level searching is acceptable as well.

Comment: MongoDB can't do that. You should do it in the app, or use another data store for searching.

Comment: ok, I'd appreciate any suggestions for doing it in the app as well

Comment: I think this is called "fuzzy searching". Try googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [phonetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) relevent to implementing "sounds like" matching.  These have varying effectiveness depending on cultural differences such as spelling, pronunciation, and languages used within your corpus of names.

A recent article [Using Fuzzy Matching to Search by Sound with Python](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/how-tos/phonetic-hashing/index.html) provides a helpful overview of some available options:

- [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)
- [NYSIIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NYSIIS)
- [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone)

Comment: Thanks. The link is a very good starting point to solving my problem